# How to get an enum reference from a reference to a child type of the enum?

Tags: rust

I have an enum type `Shape` that contains two types `Rect` and `Circle`. now there is a function that can find `&Rect` or `&Circle` objects, how can I get them to return as `&Shape`?

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rect {}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Circle {}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Shape {
    R(Rect),
    C(Circle),
}

struct Container {
    rects: Vec<(usize, Rect)>,
    circls: Vec<(usize, Circle)>,
}

impl Container {
    fn find_shape(&self, id: usize) -> Option<&Shape> {
        let optr = self.rects.iter().find(|x| x.0 == id);
        if let Some((_, r)) = optr {
            return Some(&Shape::R(r)); // expected struct `Rect`, found `&Rect`
        }
        let optc = self.circls.iter().find(|x| x.0 == id);
        if let Some((_, c)) = optc {
            return Some(c); // expected enum `Option<&Shape>` found reference `&Circle`
        }
        return None;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let cont = Container {
        rects: vec![(0, Rect {}), (2, Rect {})],
        circls: vec![(1, Circle {}), (3, Circle {})],
    };
    let s = cont.find_shape(1).unwrap();
    println!("shape is {:?}", s);
}
```

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a0e9dde537728f779e14c047eea2a891

Comment: It looks like an XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Alternatively you can store all of your shapes in the same list and then you'll get a `Option<&Shape>` from `self.shapes.iter().find`

Comment: Also, how big are your shapes? If you can make them `Copy` then this whole issue goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> now there is a function that can find `&Rect` or `&Circle` objects, how can I get them to return as `&Shape`?

It can't, in the same way you can't get e.g. an `&Option<String>` from an `&String`.

Shape is, in essence,

```rust
struct Shape {
    discr: u8,
    content: union { _1: Rect, _2: Circle }
}
```

The solution is to either modify `Shape` to store references, or to have a secondary type which does that (e.g. `ShapeRef`).

The latter is quite common.

Comment: Well, `&String` -> `&Option<String>` is not a good example, because you actually [_can_ do that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=11548a46920d3644d824186119ece074)... This is because `String` is null-pointer optimized (though this is not guaranteed), so `String` and `Option<String>` have the same size. But the general idea is correct.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Violating the API contract does not count as ‘you actually can’.

Comment: @user3840170 Perhaps, but I still think it's better to choose another example.